# Flutters Push Notifications without FCM or is it a must?

Tags: flutter, mobile, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying out the push notifications for flutter apps, so I was wondering, is using `FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging)` a must use for push notifications or not? Can I do this without FCM? `NOTE:`I tried using `FCM` and it works when the app is offline, in the background and foreground. I tried just the local push notifications with an alarm app and it only works while the app is in the background or foreground, not when the app is offline. I want to build a push notification system that sends data that works like this `Some system -> My API -> My mobile App`, can I work like that with a flutter app? Or do I need to go like this `Some system -> My API -> FCM -> My mobile App`. I know FCM is cross platform so is probably the best, but I just want to know my other options too.

Thanks in advance for your help and advice!

Answer (score 1):

The OS shows push notifications, and it doesn't matter what kind of technology you're using to create the app. All you need is to get unique token and send it to the server, so it can send a notification to the phone. Thus, you need a service to do that for you. FCM is one of them. There are other options like OneSignal, Amazon AWS, Pusher and others.

Comment: Thanks for the info! One more thing, can Amazon AWS work with both platforms, iOS and Android?

Comment: Yes it can. All push notification services work with both platforms. Google for Amazon Device Messaging (ADM) for more information.

Comment: I did Google for ADM, but most of the articles/tutorials/examples use FCM with ADM. So my question is here, why use ADM when you can just use FCM alone? Or I can just use ADM without FCM?

Comment: I've never seen any tutorial about FCM and ADM at the same time. Most of them are about FCM and very few about ADM.

Comment: Link to Firebase for Flutter docs by the way: https://firebase.flutter.dev